# '3rd Friday of the Month' to a timestamp in PLPGSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a database column giving me information on how often a file comes in.

```
Frequency_month
-------------
3rd Friday of the month
2nd Tuesday of the month
3rd Thursday of the month
```

I need to update this column and have it be a timestamp. e.g.

```
Frequency_month
-------------
2020-05-21 00:00:00
2020-05-11 00:00:00
2020-05-20 00:00:00
```

How can I accomplish this using postgres PLPGSQL language?

Comment: How do you decide the month is May?

Comment: Is the information really given in string form? Then your job is hard, because you have to parse the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following yields what your looking for. As far a parsing the Frequency_month it imposes the following restrictions:

- The first character in the string is a digit indicating the relative
  number.
- This is followed 2 characters ordinal spec (st, nd, etc) and a space.
  Actually any 3 characters, they are not checked.
- Position 5 - 7 con the first 3 characters of the English day of week (dow).

If any of those are not satisfied you will need to change the S1 subquery.
Further it requires you to provide a date of reference. This may be any date in the month of interest. See comment by @sddk.

It proceeds as follows:

1. Parse the above extracting the week number, day of week, and last
   day of the prior month. (S1).
2. Determine the ISODOW id numbers for the day of week specified and
   DOW for last of prior month. (S2).
3. Using the ISODOW id numbers Determine, determine the first
   occurrence of the target day in the target month. (S3).
4. Adjust the date from #3 by the additional weeks. (S4).
5. Finally, if the resulting date in #4 in still in the target month
   return the date form #4. If it is not the same month then return
   null. This occurs when there in no nth dow in the month or the dow
   is incorrectly specified.

I have wrapped the above into a SQL function making parameterization easy. See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b9e6f9a3b85c5a0fe650177976cafa76).

```
create or replace
function frequency_month( frequency_string text  
                         , target_month     date
                         ) 
    returns date
   language sql 
as $$
    with day_names( l_days) as 
         ( values (array['mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun']) ) 
    select -- if the calculated date in still in the target month return that date else return null
            -- covers invalid week in frequency 6th Friday or 0th Monday 
            case when extract(month from target_date) = extract (month from  target_month) 
                 then target_date
                 else null
            end
      from ( -- Advance from first dow in month the number of weeks to desirded dates  
             --select (first_of_mon + (7*(rel_num-1)) * interval '1 day')::date target_date
             select (first_of_mon + (rel_num-1) * interval '1 week')::date target_date
                from ( -- with last day of prior month get first DOW week of target month
                       select case when dow_day_nbr <= from_day_nbr 
                                    then (from_date +  (dow_day_nbr-from_day_nbr+7) * interval '1 days' )::date 
                                    else (from_date +  (dow_day_nbr-from_day_nbr) * interval '1 days' )::date 
                               end first_of_mon
                             ,  rel_num
                         from ( -- Pick up ISODOW numbers 
                                select array_position(l_days, (substring(to_char(from_date, 'day'),1,3))) as  from_day_nbr 
                                      , array_position(l_days, lower(substring(rel_dow,1,3)))  as dow_day_nbr
                                      , from_date
                                      ,  rel_num
                                   from day_names 
                                   cross join ( -- get last day of prior month, desired relative day, relative dow  
                                                select substr(frequency_string,1,1)::integer rel_num
                                                      , lower(substr(frequency_string,5,3)) rel_dow
                                                      , (date_trunc('month',target_month)  - interval '1 day')::date from_date
                                               ) s1
                                ) s2
                       ) s3
            ) s4;
$$;
```

Note: The demo also includes a standalone version if a function is not desired.